# Examples of $\lim_{m \to \infty} \int_0^m f(x)dx$ exists but $\lim_{m \to \infty} \int_0^m |f(x)|dx$ doesn't exist？

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

I finally thought some examples for this, which is the following:

For the first one, can I use $f(x)=\sin x$?

For second one, can I use $f(x)=\frac{1}{\epsilon}$when $x \in (0, \frac{\epsilon}{2})$; $f(x)=-\frac{1}{\epsilon}$when $x \in (\frac{\epsilon}{2},\epsilon)$?

but I am not sure if it is right. Could someone kindly help me look at this? Thanks!

Comment: you statement and your problem (b) is different.

Comment: @Yimin Sorry. I just assume it is a typo of the question. I guess the question mean $lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\int_0^{\epsilon}|f(x)|dx$ doesn't exist for part (b). Maybe it is not a typo. I am not sure but this is what the original question look like.

Comment: Maybe you can to try $f(x)=\mathcal{X}_{\mathbb{R- Q}}-\mathcal{X}_{\mathbb{Q}}$, where $\mathcal{X}_A$ is the characteristic function of set $A$, for problem (a).

Comment: your $f$ for (b) should be a fixed function, not a function of $\epsilon$, assuming you are correct about the typo.

Answer (score 0):

for a.

since $\sum \dfrac{1}{k} \to \infty$ and $\sum\dfrac{1}{k}(-1)^k < \infty$, you can use piecewise constant function.

for b. I doubt if the function exists. since $\int_{N}^{\infty}|f| > |\int_{N}^{\infty} f|$, if integral of $|f|$ converges, then integral of $f$ must converge too.

Answer (score 0):

No: for the first one, the integral
$$ \int_0^m \sin{x} \, dx = \cos{m}-1, $$
which does not tend to a limit as $m \to \infty$ for general $m$ (since the cosine oscillates without decreasing).
Consider instead something like
$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{(-1)^n}{n} & n-1 \leqslant x < n \end{cases}, $$
and then the integral becomes
$$ \int_0^m f(x) \, dx = \sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor m \rfloor} \frac{(-1)^k}{k} + (m-\lfloor m \rfloor) \frac{(-1)^m}{m}, $$
($\lfloor m \rfloor$ being the largest integer that does not exceed $m$) although I may have the top index slightly incorrect.

This works since the last term tends to zero, and the alternating harmonic series converges, but the harmonic series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 1/n$ does not.

For the second, your answer should not depend on $\varepsilon$. Depending on how you have defined the nonexistence of limits, you can create a function so that the integral of the absolute value does not exist at all, so it can't have a limit. Substituting $y=1/x$ makes this easier to think about: then the integral is
$$ \int_{1/\varepsilon}^{\infty} f(1/y) \frac{dy}{y^2}, $$
for which a modification of the previous example will work.